# Push plugin - Found item String/google_app_id more than one time

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic2 and I just installed Push plugin into the App, and now its createing a duplicate of @string/google_app_id

Even if i delete one of them, when i run the project, ionic creates another one and I can't compile the app due to this error.

So this is what i get in the strings.xml

```
<string name="google_app_id">@string/google_app_id</string>
<string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">XXXXXXXXXX</string>
```

I tried removing the platform and the plugin and add it again to the proyect, but the error keeps showing.

Thank you all!!

Comment: Could you please share your config.xml?

Comment: Sure, here: https://pastebin.com/eEeQKN5x

Comment: Didn't find any push plugin in config.xml. Are you using [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/) plugin, right?

Comment: Yes, I have it installed. Also I tried to remove the plugin and add it again, and still have 41 lines.

Comment: This is the other config.xml that i have in the android platform: https://pastebin.com/9vf8BKdK

Comment: Remove your plugin again. And try to install it by this command `ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID=XXXXXXXXX --save`

Comment: I did it and still the same. Now adds this line in the config.xml     <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="~1.10.0">
        <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="XXXXXX" />
    </plugin>

Comment: In the strings.xml still adds     <string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">XXXXX</string>

Comment: `<string name="google_app_id">@string/google_app_id</string>` this line is still present or only this line `<string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">XXXXX</string>`

Comment: Both are present. If I remove the plugin, removes the "translatable" line, but if I add the addon, its added again.

Comment: actually this line `<string name="google_app_id">@string/google_app_id</string>`  is the unnecessary line.

Comment: Could be, but if I execute "ionic run android" its added anyway. So thats why both are there.

Comment: Could you please tell me push plugin version?

Comment: package.json   "@ionic-native/push": "^3.4.4", 

And phonegap-plugin-push" spec="~1.10.0"

Comment: I was using 1.8.4. I updated my push plugin to check this issue. But in my case only `<string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">XXXXX</string>` line is added and run properly.

Comment: I'm using firebase plugin also, its the only thing I have from google, that plugin could be causing the problem??

Comment: Yes, firebase plugin add this `<string name="google_app_id">@string/google_app_id</string>`. In that case remove both plugin. Then 1st add push plugin and then add firebase plugin. Hope this will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you @Math10 i will try!!

Comment: Hi! I tried what you said, but... still the same, create both google_app_id :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see [here](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase#notes-about-phonegap-build) that the firebase plugin does not handle the app id and api key.

In your case you can do this after installing the firebase plugin. Go to plugins folder and open `cordova-plugin-firebase\plugin.xml` and remove these lines,

```
<config-file parent="/resources" target="res/values/strings.xml">
        <string name="google_app_id">@string/google_app_id</string>
</config-file>
```

Then add the android platform. Now you can build/run your android app.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue introduced with version 0.1.24

replaced:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="^0.1.24" />
```

for:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="0.1.22" />
```

removed and readded the platform and is working fine!
No need to touch the plugin code

Comment: Don't hesitate to provide a link to the changelog.

Answer (score 0):

I used this command bellow:

```
$ cordova clean android
```